# Visualize logistic mixed-effects regression

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm running a logistic mixed-effects model using this formula (data below):

```
library(sjPlot)
library(emmeans)
library(effects)

# mixed-effects model:
m_comp_lin <- glmer(Last_G_prop_new ~ Preselected_0 + (1 | PP_by_anon) + (1 | File), 
                    data = df)
summary(m_comp_lin)
plot_model(m_comp_lin, type = "eff", terms = c("Preselected_0"), 
           title = ""
           )
```

The resulting plot is unsatifactory:

[image]

What I actually have in mind is something more like this:

[image]

How can the model **vizualization be improved**?

```
df <- structure(list(File = c("F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", 
"F01", "F01", "F01", "F01", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", "F04", 
"F04", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", "F07", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", "F08", 
"F08", "F08", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", 
"F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", 
"F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", "F12", 
"F12", "F12", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", 
"F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F16", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", 
"F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", 
"F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", "F18", 
"F18", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", 
"F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", "F20", 
"F20", "F22", "F22", "F22", "F22", "F22", "F22", "F22", "F22", 
"F22", "F22", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", 
"F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", 
"F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", 
"F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", 
"F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", "F23", 
"F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", 
"F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19", "F19"), PP_by_anon = c("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
NA, NA, "AAAAAAAAAAo", NA, "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", NA, 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", NA, 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", 
"SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "SSSSSSSSSSd", 
"SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", 
"SSSSSSSSSSd", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", 
"JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", 
"JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", 
"OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "LLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"KKKKKKKKKn"), Last_G_prop_new = c(1, 1, 1, 0.268478924862553, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.967811158798283, 0.886535552193646, 0.872596153846154, 
0.690683229813665, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.0948207171314741, 0.945754716981132, 
1, 1, 0.968316831683168, 0.558232931726908, 1, 0.186448385629832, 
0.286250939143501, 0.164767747589833, 1, 0.334851936218679, 0.891011235955056, 
0.198135198135198, 0.253105273874975, 0.65399534522886, 0.509803921568627, 
0.646516393442623, 0.573170731707317, 0.589229144667371, 0.44213649851632, 
0.100802407221665, 0.391482112436116, 0.216799091940976, 0.338888888888889, 
0.788166544923302, 0.2375, 1, 1, 0.280369367935042, 0.14375, 
1, 0.783766233766234, 0.837784371909001, 1, 1, 0.477361853832442, 
1, 0.696142027995903, 1, 0.691646778042959, 0.92102615694165, 
1, 1, 0.684470246734398, 0.407130730050934, 0.762, 0.571134626690182, 
1, 0.94020618556701, 0.88993288590604, 0.0587904360056259, 1, 
0.45097037793667, 0.917167381974249, 0.596136567834681, 0.356140350877193, 
0.335489086499596, 0.148545861297539, 1, 1, 0.0346307532928815, 
1, 0.268028846153846, 1, 0.399206349206349, 0.475932611311673, 
0.0872865275142315, 0.731707317073171, 0.92755905511811, 0.637254901960784, 
1, 0.101538461538462, 0.791596638655462, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0.411274509803922, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.870157068062827, 0.236621534493875, 
0.947232037691402, 1, 1, 0.258741258741259, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.327272727272727, 
1, 1, 1, 0.576605504587156, 1, 0.346805349182764, 0.908885298869144, 
1, 1, 0.744615384615385, 1, 1, 1, 0.114783987316686, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.92, 1, 0.414646464646465, 0.0521472392638037, 0.476190476190476, 
0.63841642228739, 1, 0.344582593250444, 0.457099849473156, 1, 
1, 0.048780487804878, 0.325622775800712, 0.801178203240059, 1, 
0.67378640776699, 0.281512605042017, 1, 0.0612186788154898, 0.363516192994052, 
1, 0.234183673469388, 0.858426966292135, 0.482734319943622, 0.936170212765957, 
1, 0.135734072022161, 0.659006211180124, 0.60523138832998, 1, 
0.775, 1, 0.91168, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.637514384349827, 0.71178247734139, 
1, 0.0956204379562044, 0.00733333333333333, 1, 0.746478873239437, 
1, 1, 0.00231660231660232, 1, 1, 0.604638903531892, 0.776677172444845, 
1, 1, 0.640356083086053, 1, 0.60134436401241, 1, 0.392484076433121, 
0.899465425073289, 0.223900488671701, 1, 1, 0.456339417858905, 
1, 1, 1, 0.0781925343811395, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.371956339210747, 
0.66044142614601, 1, 0.668141592920354, 0.235119047619048, 0.978021978021978, 
0.542203147353362, 1, 0.00807955251709136, 0.125135427952329, 
0.489535941765241, 0.65336856010568, 0.154856293359762, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0.224127906976744, 0.271759382486026, 0.387314439946019, 
1, 0.743661971830986, 0.834065397755002, 1, 0.721991701244813, 
1, 0.389337641357027, 0.0659062103929024, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.628493524199046, 
0.807921866521975, 0.274065685164213, 0.288434079009995, 0.0633333333333333, 
1, 0.807476635514019, 1, 0.315603799185889, 0.0278385075061944, 
0.22837653478854, 0.394160583941606, 1, 1, 0.396850393700787, 
0.467036172695449, 1, 0.175278622087133, 0.499613102914625, 0.489586388970373, 
0.802830940988836, 1, 0.375563755637556, 1, 0.726451612903226, 
0.933620159803319, 1, 0.482439926062847, 0.531076301162203, 1, 
0.729323308270677, 0.134835128958537, 0.72874251497006, 1, 0.830020562028787, 
0.0956968529222865, 0.919400187441425, 1, 1, 0.330786026200873, 
0.103013635842787, 0.541375291375291, 0.497390826695963, 1, 1, 
0.592891278375149, 1, 0.12290931410158, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.46241610738255, 
0.0849342770475228, 1, 0.745214220601641, 0.0133399209486166, 
1, 0.919066715275246, 0.738897022938019, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.6331597917501, 
0.117180347879158, 1, 0.0208926875593542, 0.762093926553672, 
1, 0.748275862068966, 1, 0.395027624309392, 0.999999999999998, 
0.0253405994550409, 1, 0.0377335888835649, 0.99999999999998, 
0.662013662013662, 1, 0.0621130030959752, 0.371640937678674, 
1, 1, 0.450445726271631, 0.742954475069681, 1, 1, 0.512876413680338, 
1), Preselected_0 = c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", 
"No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", 
"Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes")), row.names = c(NA, 
-338L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Well, you basically want to plot predictions. The obvious first step would be to calculate predictions on population and subject levels over the range of your predictor.

Comment: Well, and how would I do that?

Comment: I have posted an [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/99049/11849) showing how to do it with a `nlme::lme` model. It's equally as easy with a `lme4::glmer` model.